# Formatting \n list of IPv4 addresses into json

Tags: json, bash, formatting, sh, jq

I have a list of IPv4 addresses being output in a list each separated by \n. The program I would like to import these into is expecting it in this format:

```
{
  "data":[
      { "IP":"127.0.0.1"  },
      { "IP":"192.168.0.1" }
  ]
}
```

Input data for the above would have been this:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
```

I've looked in the [jq cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) for ideas but the closest I've been able to string together is using [] not {}, not inside data, and only has the value without key.

```
jq -sR '[sub("\n$";"") | splits("\n") | sub("^ +";"") | [splits(" +")]]'
```

Outputs:

```
[
  [
    "127.0.0.1"
  ],
  [
    "192.168.0.1"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
jq -Rn '{data: [ {IP: inputs} ] }' input.txt
```

If this seems a bit magical, you might like to use the more mundane variant:

```
jq -Rn '{data: [ inputs | {IP: .} ] }' input.txt
```

Of course, in practice, you might also want to remove extraneous whitespace in the input, filter out comments, perform validity checking or filter out invalid input ...

Comment: `inputs | select(length>0)` to remove potential empty lines on the raw input file?